# Error while handling payments through Magento API with Authorize.net

Tags: magento, e-commerce, payment, xml-rpc, authorize.net

I am using the [Magento APIs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) to build a custom store. I am able to create a shopping cart and add a product to the cart and set shipping and billing addresses. I have configured Authorize.net as the payment method in the Magento Admin backend. I am able to get the listing the [payment method list API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartPayment/cart_payment.list.html) call as well. I'm trying to handle the whole shopping to checkout to payment using my custom built store instead of using Magento Go's store.

The payment method that I get in the response is `pbridge_authorizenet`. Next, when I use the payment set method to apply the payment method to the cart I am getting the following error

```
Please specify the payment information and submit it.
```

In the Magento admin, Authorize.net the `Test` option is switched on.

Any help is highly appreciated. Let me know if you need any additional details. Thanks

**Update**

This is the request for the `cart_payment.method` API call

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>call</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>c07eff7df85103344b47b4292698aaf9</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>cart_payment.method</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <array>
          <data>
            <value>
              <int>211</int>
            </value>
            <value>
              <struct>
                <member>
                  <name>po_number</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>1234</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>cc_cid</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>234</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>cc_owner</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>Debjeet</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>cc_number</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>4007000000027</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>cc_type</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>VI</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>cc_exp_year</name>
                  <value>
                    <int>2018</int>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>cc_exp_month</name>
                  <value>
                    <int>4</int>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>method</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>pbridge_authorizenet</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
              </struct>
            </value>
          </data>
        </array>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

This is the response for the `cart_payment.method` API call

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
  <fault>
    <value>
      <struct>
        <member>
          <name>faultCode</name>
          <value>
            <int>1075</int>
          </value>
        </member>
        <member>
          <name>faultString</name>
          <value>
            <string>Please specify the payment infor
mation and submit it.</string>
          </value>
        </member>
      </struct>
    </value>
  </fault>
</methodResponse>
```

Comment: Have you considered that you may need to submit the information about the payment you want the bridge to collect?

Comment: I'm implementing it through the Magento APIs. What do you mean by submitting exactly?

Comment: I don't know anything about the particular system you are working with, but if you are using a payment gateway, it generally needs to have information provided to it about what the payment is (either what they should charge for if they are collecting billing information or what the billing information is if it is pre-collected in a PCI-DSS approved manner).  It would seem from the error that this information has not been provided, which seems to indicate you missed a step in the process.

Comment: I am sending po_number, cc_cid, cc_owner, cc_number, cc_type, cc_exp_year, cc_exp_month and the method in the api request. Updated with the XML req/res.

Comment: not sure then, though on an unrelated note, have you verified that the server it will be running on is PCI compliant?  You can't handle CC data without having a fair number of security requirements you have to meet.

Comment: Yes, we won't move to production without compliance. But, first this needs to work at least in the sandbox/test environment.